# Flatpak installation from flathub.org doesnt add flatpak apps to elementaryos appcenter

Tags: appcenter, flatpak

In elementaryos 5.1 (Hera) appcenter doesnt show the downloaded flatpak apps or option to download the flatpak app. (even though I downloaded firefox and libreoffice from flathub.org)

How can I enable flatpak apps in appcenter without sideloading?

Answer (score 0):

There is ongoing work to support this. See the developers git resource: [Support systemwide flatpaks](https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/pull/1308) I can't give a specific date as to when that feature would be ready, but I would hope it would be complete by the release of elementary OS 6.0.

Old post from omgubuntu: [elementary OS Now Has Support for Flatpak Apps](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/elementary-os-flatpak-support)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the Flatpak remote manually or side-load a single app manually from a remote to make applications from that remote available in AppCenter.
This is described in the [Flathub setup documentation for elementaryOS](https://flatpak.org/setup/elementary%20OS/).
To add Flathub as a remote without side-loading, just type the following command on the command-line.

```
$ flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub \
  https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Once this completes, restart and AppCenter will show applications from Flathub.